# ASPxPageControl switching tabs from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm trying to use ASPxPageControl ase a template for my wizard. I put buttons on each page and connected it to javascript which simply changes active page, for example:

```
Pc1Client.SetActiveTab(Pc1Client.GetTab(1));
```

It works correct when tabs are visible but when I set

ASPxPageControl1.ShowTabs = "false"

then when trying to change tab by clicking my button an error is raised (sth that formant with that name already exists or sth like that, i ve got error message in polish
)

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I used (The ASPxPageControl's version is 10.1.6):

```
<dx:ASPxPageControl ID="ASPxPageControl1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="2" ClientInstanceName="pc" EnableClientSideAPI="True">
    <TabPages>
        <dx:TabPage Text="Tab 0">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
                    0<br />
                </dx:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:TabPage>
        <dx:TabPage Text="Tab 1">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
                    1</dx:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:TabPage>
        <dx:TabPage Text="Tab 2">
            <ContentCollection>
                <dx:ContentControl runat="server">
                    2</dx:ContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
        </dx:TabPage>
    </TabPages>
</dx:ASPxPageControl>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="pc.SetActiveTab(pc.GetTab(0));" />


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ASPxPageControl1.ShowTabs = false;
}
```

It works correctly here.

Comment: In this case its true, works correctly but when I have grids in this tab pages there is an error. maybe im doing something wrong I need to check it, anyway thanks

Comment: Please post your aspx markup here.  I will review it and let you know how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you do `ASPxPageControl1.ShowTabs = "false"` tabs do not render on page and they are not available through JavaScript

Comment: Is there any way in which I  can hide them and still make them available by javascript? I dont want user to be able to change those tabs manually

Comment: @snorlaks you can hide them initialy by setting its style in CSS to "display:none"

Comment: Which style ?  Style of what ?

Comment: @snorlaks show me your aspx. Also you can have a look at this demo http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/TabControl/ServerSide.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem and make your code work, set the ASPxPageControl's EnableClientSideAPI property to true.  In this case, everything should work properly.

Comment: After setting this property and writing in Page_Load event :

ASPxPageControl1.ShowTabs = false;

there is still the same problem while trying to change current tab from javascript.

It works when this property (ASPxPageControl1.ShowTabs) isnt set to false,

thanks